# rewrite rule in Nginx

Tags: nginx

rewrite rule:

```
location / {         
    rewrite ^/([a-z]+)/$ /index.jsp?a=$1 last;
}
```

and I create a directory `/abc/` in the root directory ,and put a `index.html` in `/abc/`

when I access `http://localhost/abc/` ,I can't get `/abc/index.html`

How to make `http://localhost/abc/` can be access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create an extra location block

```
location /abc {
    root /your/root/dir/abc/;
}
```

Comment: thanks @mre666 ,In fact there are many other directories, I can not be defined one by one, there is no other way out?

Comment: I usually have just one top level directory like this and then all other static directories below, so I only have to add one extra location block.

Comment: thanks @mre666,I would like to determine whether there is a real directory, not directory then rewrite, I am not sure whether it is reasonable

Comment: it sounds a little complex. you could do a custom error handler that passes 404 on to another script (fallback), see nginx docs: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#error_page